# fontawesome not displaying in local

Tags: laravel-5, fontawesome-4.4.0

I am using fontawesome in my laravel project, the problem is that it will not display if I use it in local without using CDN.

`<link href="{{ URL::asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

`NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/mysite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3"`

`"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/mysite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3"`

`NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/mysite/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3`

here is my fullpath of font-awesome.min.css

> C:\wamp\www\mysite\public\css\

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using the URL helpers incorrectly.

If `font-awesome.min.css` is inside `public/css` then you want to be referencing it just using the [`asset()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-asset) helper - you do not need to add the `URL` facade too.

So just tweak your `<link>` tag a little like so:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/font-awesome.min.css') }}" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Hi @James,I tried you solution but still not working

Comment: @jemz can you confirm the full file path for `font-awesome.min.css` please?

Comment: I put the full path in my question

Comment: @jemz have you followed the correct steps to use font awesome locally? It looks like you haven't got the font files in your `public/fonts` directory... http://fontawesome.io/get-started/

Comment: what do you mean the steps ?the fonts are place inside the fonts folder separate to css folder

Comment: @jemz yes but are they located at `public/fonts`? Your 404 errors suggest that those files cannot be found

Comment: it is there I donwloaded again and put the fonts folder inside the public folder and it doesn't work

Comment: @jemz when you follow the 404 error link can you see the contents of them?

Comment: yes I can see the content, I viewed source then click the link of fontawesome then it display the content of it

Comment: yeah me too, I am pulling my hair ...I don't know how to fix this

Comment: @jemz why can't you just use a CDN?

Comment: because the server has no internet connection. and they want to run the application in local

Comment: I put public asset('public/css/fontawesome.min.css')